# Loop filter R and C values rounding off

Tags: filter, pll

I am trying to design Loop filter with ADIsimPLL tool from Analog devices.

I got below values for loop filter:-

C1 --> 14.3 nF

C2 --> 69.9 nF

R1 --> 3.05 k

How can I round off these values to standard values?

Should I consider higher roundoff values or lower round off values?

At the moment I am thinking of using below values:-

C1 --> 14.3 nF --> 0.01 uF + 0.01 uF (in parallel)

C2 --> 69.9 nF --> 0.1 uF

R1 --> 3.05 k --> 3 k or 3.3 k

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pick something, plug the values back in, and see whether the parameters you get are okay. If not, try changing something.

Comment: Round according to which standard values? For example a 3.05k 0.5% resistor can exist, and in theory a 14.3nF 1% capacitor could exist, but a 69.9nF is not a standard value while 69.8nF 1% is. Also you did not say within which tolerance you need them rounded.

Comment: Please DON'T SHOUT in your question title.

Comment: If the circuit is in the development stage, use pots/tuning capacitor for the series leg. On the pcb leave space for series/parallel components, since this is a lower frequency node in a typical pll system.

Answer (score 2):

I would use C1:15nf, C2: 68nf and R1: 2K7 or 3K

Comment: 15nF is 0.015uF, So I will use 2 0.01uF in parallel. 68nF is 0.068uF I need use 7 0.01uF in parallel. I have single pad I can mount 2 capacitors on one another to make them in parallel(for 0.015uF).